# doctrine composite primary key migration

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-migrations

1. I have Doctrine entity with composite primary key in my Symfony project:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`content_article_serie_reference`")
 */
class ArticleSerieReference
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="series")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $article;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Serie")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="serie", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $serie;
```

2. Run `bin/console doctrine:migration:diff` to create migration
3. Doctrine creates PRIMARY KEY (article, serie), INDEX(article), INDEX(serie) for MySQL database.

Is there any way to tell Doctrine not to create this useless "article" index?

Comment: One way would be to alter the migration to remove the index. Another possible solution would be to specify the index(s) on the table at the entity class level. I haven't messed with specifying indexes as of yet in my own project [Doctrine Index Annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-index)